# S-On, No OS, UNLOCKED, No TWRP and want to install custom OS on HTC One M8

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, custom-roms, htc, htc-one-m9

I have a HTC One M9 and would like to install the [cRDroid ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2753248). 
When going into the bootloader I see:

- Software status: Modified
- UNLOCKED
- S-ON
- (Now the options)

  - REBOOT
  - REBOOT TO BOOTLOADER
  - BOOT TO DOWNLOAD MODE
  - BOOT TO RECOVERY MODE
  - POWER DOWN

I have tried to flash the OS via fastboot `fastboot flash boot boot.zip` this returned:
`FAILED (remote: cannot flash this partition in s-on state)`.
When I tried to boot with `fastboot boot boot.zip` I got:

```
creating boot image...
creating boot image - 381388800 bytes
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [ 12.064s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: dtb not found)
```

Also booting to download mode got me `Failed to boot to download mode`

Comment: Guess I'm not sure what you are trying to do... Why not just flash TWRP, then flash the CRdroid room image with TWRP?

Comment: Won't let me flash it. Same as when flashing boot

Comment: So "fastboot flash recovery twrp.img" fails while unlocked? How did you get to this state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problems turned out to be dead NAND flash, which will need to be replaced